# number of control points for B spline curve

Tags: curve-fitting, spline

I am trying to use B spline curve fitting. The order of B spline curve is 4. When I have many control points, it works well. However if the number of control points is small such as two, my program will crash. I realize that the number of control points is related to number of knots and the order. Can anyone help me clarify the relationship or give some links on it?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're simply reading out of bounds, which is not a specific issue of calculating splines. To calculate a b-spline of degree `n`, you'll need at least `n + 1` points.

To simplify and show the issue:

- The easiest way of interpolation is linear interpolation - just draw a line between two points.
- If you've got only one point, you can't interpolate anything, simply due to the fact that you don't know where to draw.
- For a quadratic interpolation, you'll need at least three points, etc.
- In a similar way, you'll need at least 5 points for a b-spline of 4th degree.

A really nice [online demo can be found here](http://geometrie.foretnik.net/files/NURBS-en.swf):

[image: Example screenshot of NURBSdemo.swf]

- Pick any *b-spline* demo on the lower left side, I'd just go for the *linear* one.
- On the right you're now able to set the *number of control points* as well as the *degree of the curve*.
- Feel free to try around, also by moving the points around with your mouse.

Comment: Thanks. If control points, knot vector and degree of b spline are given and meets the requirement, the b spline is defined. If I hope to perform b spline curve fitting, what should I do?

Comment: @JoggingSong I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know how to do least square curve fitting with B-spline. Someone gives me the link:http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/BSplineCurveLeastSquaresFit.pdf. I am reading the document. Do the curve fitting try to optimize control points?

Comment: No, "least square" refers to the attempt to lower the amount of errors as much as possible. You don't modify your control points, but you're trying to keep your calculated curve as close to the control points as possible (i.e. never "oversteering" a point). Check out [this question and it's accepted answer](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11153/least-squares-approximation-question) to read more about this and also see some example images.

Comment: There are three parameters that define one B-spline curve:control points, knot vector and degree of the B-spline curve. I mean that which parameters are optimized to minimize the error in the least square way. Maybe for the curve fitting, control points and degree of the B-spline are give, so only knot vector is unknown and is optimized.

Comment: In LS fitting, typically the degree and the number of segment of the B-spline is pre-defined. A proper knot vector is derived from the degree and number of segments and sometimes the parameters of the data points, then the control points are found to minimize the error in the least square way.

Comment: While you could get your algorithm to try different degrees, the number of segments/control points stays the same (those are fixed and can't be changed). Otherwise you could just put all control points on a straight line and call that your spline; which would be a perfect 100% match.

Comment: You should probably replace every instance of "order" in the post with "degree", otherwise it's a bit confusing (especially in splines, "order" usually refers to one plus the degree).

Comment: @Ponkadoodle Done

Answer (score 3):

Two control points is not sufficient to define a B-spline of order 4. For B-splines, the number of knots needs to equal the sum of number of control points and order. A single segment degree 3 B-spline will require 4 control points and 8 knot values. So, to calculate a B-spline with order N, you at least need N points. That will give you a B-spline with single segment. If you have more points, then the resulting B-spline will have more segments.

Comment: Currently I am trying to perform b spline curve fitting. I will determine number of the segment in term of the number of input points, the formula is that number of segments equals (number input points) / 10 + 1). I always use a B spline of order 4. If the number of input points is small, it will cause problem. How can B spline be used for curve fitting?

Comment: Look like you want to do Least Square fitting with B-splines. If this is the case, you can refer to this article (http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/BSplineCurveLeastSquaresFit.pdf)

Comment: I am reading the document. In the document, the input data is called sample data and the optimization is done to find the control data to minimize the error. I have one question. Maybe the basis functions of the B-spline curve is determined by knot vector. Then the knot vector is uniform.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is which parameter is optimized for least square B-spline fitting. From the document of geometric tools, it says that control points Qi need to be determined. If so, the basis functions is known and the basis functions is calculated from knot vector, can I say knot vector is not related to control points and is uniform.

Comment: Yes. it is the control points that are to be determined by the LS fitting. If you have sufficient number of data points, you can use uniform knot vector. But using a knot vector that is adaptive to the data point distribution will often have a better result.

Answer (score 2):

As others stated, the number of control points is equal to the number of knots minus the order of the bspline basis. Thus you cannot have an arbitrary combination of order, say k, and knot vector for your bspline function/curve once you fix the control points.

A very useful link for theory on b-splines and nurbs curves is the following: 
http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/index.html

There you can find the relationship of number of control points with dimensionality of knot vector etc as well as detailed examples and some algorithms.

Depending on your needs, you may also wish to check "The NURBS book" by Piegl and Tiller 
[http://www.amazon.com/NURBS-Book-Monographs-Visual-Communication/dp/3540615458](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540615458)

they have done an amazing job and in their book they include working algorithms.

The curve fitting problem of a b-spline to data is a rather large subject since you have to take care to avoid over/under fitting. There are several approaches, and most involve including a curvature penalty term. The literature is vast, but you can find a lot of information and a great starting point in the book by Hastie et. al. "The elements of statistical learning" which you can legally download from the authors site: 
http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/

The curve fitting problem is covered to some extent in all references I gave. Good luck.